# Python counting lines in files using exact locations

Tags: python, list, for-loop, count

I know this is straightforward but I am not quite understanding how to make my for loop work.

My first file is a long list of two columns of data:

```
ROW    VALUE
0      165   
1      115
2      32
3      14
4      9
5      0
6      89
7      26
.       .
406369  129
406370  103
```

My second file is a list of important row numbers:

```
1
43
192
so on
```

All I want to do is go to the row number of interest in file 1, and then walk down, row by row, until the value column hits zero.  The output will then be simply a list of the important row numbers followed by the count of the lines there are until the first file reaches zero.  For instance, the output for important row number "1" from file #2, should be 3, because there are three lines and then the values reaches 0 in file #1.  I appreciate any help!  I have some script I have started and can post it in an edit if that is helpful.  THANK YOU!

EDIT:

Some script I have started:

```
for line in important_rows_file:
    line = line.strip().split()
    positive_starts.append(int(line[2])

countsfile = []
for line in file:
    line = line.strip().split()
    countsfile.append([line[0]] + [line[1]])

count = 0
i = 0
for i in range(0, len(countsfile)):
    for start in positive_starts:
    if int(countsfile[start + i][1]) > 0:
            count = count + 1
    else:
            count = count
```

.... not sure what is next

Comment: Should row `4` yield `1` in your case?

Comment: *"I have some script I have started and can post it in an edit if that is helpful."* Yes, please do that.

Comment: Agreeing with @MikeSherrill'Catcall'.  You should always post what you have tried.

Comment: row 4 should yield 0, since there are no rows between row 4 and the next 0 in the value column @sberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it.

The first way builds a dictionary in memory for all row numbers.  This would be a good way to do it if a. You are going to re-use this same data over and over (you can store it and read it back in) or b. You are going to process a lot of rows from the second file (ie. most of the rows need this done).  The second way just does a one-off for a given row number.

Given this as the input file:

```
ROW    VALUE
0      165
1      115
2      32
3      14
4      9
5      0
6      89
7      26
8      13
9      0
```

Method 1.

```
ref_dict = {}
with open("so_cnt_file.txt") as infile:
    next(infile)
    cur_start_row = 0
    cur_rows = []
    for line in infile:
        row, col = [int(val) for val in line.strip().split(" ") if val]
        if col == 0:
            for cur_row in cur_rows:
                ref_dict[cur_row] = row - cur_row - 1
            cur_start_row = row
            cur_rows = []
            continue
        cur_rows.append(row)
print ref_dict
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{0: 4, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 0, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 0}
```

Method 2

```
def get_count_for_row(row=1):
    with open("so_cnt_file.txt") as infile:
        for i in range(0, row + 2):
            next(infile)
        cnt = 0
        for line in infile:
            row, col = [int(val) for val in line.strip().split(" ") if val]
            if col == 0:
                return cnt
            cnt += 1
print get_count_for_row(1)
print get_count_for_row(6)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
3
2
```

Here is a solution that takes all of the rows of interest in a single call.

```
def get_count_for_rows(*rows):
    rows = sorted(rows)
    counts = []
    with open("so_cnt_file.txt") as infile:
        cur_row = 0
        for i in range(cur_row, 2):
             next(infile)
        while rows:
            inrow = rows.pop(0)
            for i in range(cur_row, inrow):
                next(infile)
            cnt = 0
            for line in infile:
                row, col = [int(val) for val in line.strip().split(" ") if val]
                if col == 0:
                    counts.append((inrow, cnt))
                    break
                cnt += 1
            cur_row = row
    return counts

print get_count_for_rows(1, 6)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[(1, 3), (6, 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  I will be using this on a file with many rows, is there a way I could just print every row of interest wihtout having to call each of them as in the `print get_count_for_row(1)` ?